# "What makes you think of watching a movie?" Is this sentence OK?

Tags: sentence-construction, responses

The answer for the question I want to say would be "the story", "casts", etc.

You might say "What is the factor that makes you think of watching a movie?" for that question.

(I don't know if my explanation was good enough. I hope you could understand my question.)

Comment: What makes you think of him? Or her. Or them. Or anything, really.

Comment: “What *gets you to* watch a movie?”

Answer (score 1):

> What is your favorite part about the movie?
>
> What part of the movie do you enjoy the most?

To which someone would reply something like:

> My favorite part is the cast. They have excellent acting skills

or

> I enjoy the plot of the movie, it's well crafted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think my meaning was not conveyed correctly.  The meaning of the question is: Do you consider going to the theater when the story sounds interesting, or do you consider going if the cast is good, and so on.  What makes you "consider" is the point.  I hope I could convey what I wanted to ask this time.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the sentence is grammatically correct and the idea is explicitly exhibited. The only difference is the British-America lexical structural arrangement of sentences; for instance, in British, watching a movie is wrong but seeing it is right. You only watch television in British English while you see a movie but in American English, you can watch both but I'd rather go with the British's because it's the only standard yardstick with which we can measure the originality of English existence but I could speak it the way Americans speak it when I'm in America but originally, I know it's not correct in standard English form. Language choice matters depending on settings and locations we find ourselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! >the idea is explicitly exhibited.   ... Please let me make sure that you understood the meaning what I wanted to express by the question sentence.  It's a question about the reason what make people "consider" going to the theater or rent a DVD.  Regarding movies, you might say "I want to go watch the movie becasue the story sounds very interesting" or "I want to rent the DVD because I like Leonard Dicaprio, and he is stared in that movie" and so on, and the question is to get the "story" or "Leonard Dicaprio (cast)" part.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> Why do you watch movies?

or

> What do you like about movies?

or if you're talking about a particular movie,

> Why do you want to watch this movie?

or

> What intrigues you about this movie?